# How to find smallest missing number in range with given array in Dart or Java

Tags: java, algorithm, flutter, dart

Imagine that you have a range from 1 to 6 and array arr = [1,2,3]
How to write nice algorithm where the function will return smallest possible missing number in this range according to data in an array, meaning :

```
input: arr[1, 2, 3]
output: 4 is smallest missing
```

or

```
input: arr[2, 3, 4]
output: 1 is smallest missing
```

- In case that there is no missing numbers function can give output 7, its okay.
- In case if array is empty somehow you may return 1.

I tried my best with some codes coming from [www.geeksforgeeks.com](http://www.geeksforgeeks.com) but it didn't help me.
Its okay if you write code in Java but Dart is the language that Im working on

Thanks a lot for being helpful in advance !

Comment: Homework smell!

Comment: @Mugdha hah, looks like, but actually I need it in my flutter  project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplify use a loop

```
void main() {
  //passing empty list
  print(smallestMissingNumber([]));
  //missing 3
  print(smallestMissingNumber([1,2,4,5,6,7,8]));
  //no missing element
  print(smallestMissingNumber([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
}

int smallestMissingNumber(List<int> list){
  int i = 1;
  for(; i<= list.length; i++){
    if(!list.contains(i)){
      break;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
7
```

Answer (score 0):

PseudoCode -> convert to java

```
Create a range array from [1,2,3,4,5,6].
Fetch your input array [2,3,4] whatever    
Iterate you range array and check if the number exists in input array.
First missing number is the smallest number.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final universe = List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i + 1);
  final input = [1,3,6];
  var minMissing = universe.toSet().difference(input.toSet()).reduce((cur, next) => cur < next ? cur : next);
  print(minMissing);
}
```

Result:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
int smallestMissing =-1;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(arr[i]!=i+1){
      smallestMissing = i+1;
      break;
   }
}
if(smallestMissing==-1){
   smallestMissing = arr.length;
}
```